# How to set up a local IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 network with Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, firebase, ipv6

My app just got rejected with a message saying:

```
We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on an iPad and
iPhone running iOS 10.1.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
```

I am using Firebase, but the tester couldn't perform login under IPv6 network connection.

I want to setup an IPv6 only network to test and debug my app according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html), but my Macbook doesn't have Ethernet port and I don't own a USB Ethernet adapter.

Now, I am trying to achieve it with my Windows laptop. How can I do it?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/214053/how-to-turn-your-mac-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/. Turn mac into wifi hotspot.

Comment: Buy a USB Ethernet adapter. They're cheap.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and don't know the answer for your question. By the way, let me give you a tip: sometimes Apple rejects your app because you are not using a secure connection (https).